# Drawing on camera frame continuously by using camera2 api?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am trying to draw on the surface view using the Camera2 API sample code from Google. But for some reason, the drawing disappears after the camera preview starts. I am really confused as to why this is happening.

```
private void drawonSurfaceView(){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder= mOverlay.getHolder();
        if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            //... actual drawing on canvas

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            int x = canvas.getWidth();
            int y = canvas.getHeight();


            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            Rect rect = new Rect(50, 50, x-300, y-300);
            canvas.drawRect(rect, paint );

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }


    }
```

I Have placed the code inside the setUpCameraOutputs() method.

Answer (score 1):

That's true, you cannot lock the canvas of a preview surface for drawing. Some while ago, the SurfaceView used for camera preview required special settings (see *[What does SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3525287/what-does-surfaceholder-surface-type-push-buffers-means)*), but since API 11, this happens automagically.

You can always draw on a transparent view that is above the camera preview, but this is not the recommended solution. Much better, use a SurfaceTexture for your camera live stream, and draw with OpenGL in the 2D virtual world that includes that texture. To have your drawings synchronized with the camera stream, you should hide the preview texture and draw the camera frames yourself using the same callback that you use to feed the image processing algorithm.